# sed -l option for line-wrapping is not working

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

```
sed -e 's/word1/word2/' -l 3 output > output2
```

I'm testing this command. I expected 3 characters for each line. But, it doesn't work. `output2` has the same line breaks as `output`. Have I misunderstand line-wrapping??

Comment: And where is the  sample texts to work on, please provide that!

Comment: That was just  a bunch of random texts of several lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short... yes you have misunderstood line-wrapping slightly ;)

```
-l N, --line-length=N
       specify the desired line-wrap length for the `l' command
```

So, it only works with the `l` command:

```
l      List out the current line in a ``visually unambiguous'' form.
l width
       List out the current line in a ``visually unambiguous'' form,
       breaking it at width characters.  This is a GNU extension.
```

If you want the output three characters per line, you could use this:

```
sed -nl 4 's/word1/word2/;l' output > output2
```

or this in GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/word1/word2/;l 4' output > output2
```

Note that a trailing backslash (to escape the line break) is appended if there is not actually a new line (end-of-line is indicated by `$` characters). We need to use the `-n` flag, because the `l` command is for viewing rather than editing, like the `=` command, and the line will appear as normal after `l` has output it in the requested form, unless suppressed by `-n`.

You might get more like what you actually want by simply breaking the file after every three characters:

```
sed 's/word1/word2/; s/.../&\n/g' output > output2
```

or to split after, say, 10 characters:

```
sed -r 's/word1/word2/; s/.{10}/&\n/g' output > output2
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. After reading documentation and your answer I wonder why I don't deduce the command combination like you did. I think the reason is that I don't have the basic knowledge to make scripts. I can guess what it means 's/word1/word2/;l', but I don't want to rely on the guess. I want to be precise. What should I do to be proficient with scripts like this example??

Comment: @Smile oh, just keep practising :) [Here's a resource](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html) I like for `sed` with examples.

Comment: I'm reading https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction. After that I'm gonna read the resource you provide. Is it too much?

Comment: @Smile just stop when you get bored :)